# Android Studio NPE warnings in onCreate

Tags: android, null, warnings, oncreate

Lately Android Studio has started showing me unnecessary NPE warnings for views in onCreate. The app compiles and runs properly but it's quite distracting, for instance, when the whole textView.setOnClickListener block is highlighted in yellow.
Annotations should prevent this but is there a way to do it globally from the settings without affecting the other NPE warnings?

Code sample here:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView label = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.label);

    label.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { //NPE warning for this
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           // code here
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: show your code please

Comment: Hey @IntelliJAmiya sample code added. Any help appreciated

Comment: `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.set_your_xml);`

Comment: Thanks for edit .Show your `activity_main`

Comment: Seems like he is adding each class himself... Make habit of adding `Activity`. it will automatically generate `setContentView`.

Comment: My bad. setContentView is already present in my code. I just forgot to add it up there in the sample code. Question updated now. And might I add that my app compiles and runs without any issues. As I mentioned, it's just a **warning** in yellow and not an error (red).

Comment: Then its only warning go on build and run...

Comment: @ShreeKrishna I know but most of my code in onCreate is covered in yellow highlight. It's quite distracting. Didn't happen a few days ago

Answer (score 2):

> NullPointerException is thrown when an application attempts to use an
>   object reference, having the null value. These include: Calling an
>   instance method on the object referred by a null reference.

1. You are missing to set `setContentView(R.layout.put_your_xml);`

Basically what this function does is display the Layout created thorugh XML or the Dynamically created layout view in the Screen.

Finally

```
  @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.put_your_xml);// You missing this
    TextView label = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.label);

    label.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { //NPE warning for this
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           // code here
        }
    });
}
```